# Autodesk Forge Model Properties API Returns too Many Properties - Query Not Working?

Tags: python, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am trying to write the query to get five columns from Model Properties while filtering out elements that don’t have a bboxMin value. When the results come back though, they come back with many properties that I don’t need. Could you help me figure out what I’m doing wrong?

Here is an example of my code:

```
ListLength = len(clash_docs_urn)
props_list = []
index = 0
index_list = []
state_list = []
DictList = []

while index < ListLength:
    #Specify the payload of the columns you want to get
    Dict = {
    "versionUrn": clash_docs_urn[index],
    "query": {
        "$and": [
            { "$notnull": "s.bboxMin" },
            {"$gt": [{"$count": "s.views"},0]}
            ]
        },
    "columns": {
        "lmvid": "s.lmvid",
        "bboxMin": "s.bboxMin",
        "bboxMax": "s.bboxMax",
        "externalId": "s.externalId",
        "databaseId": "s.databaseId"
        }
    }

    DictList.append(Dict)
    index = index + 1

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("developer.api.autodesk.com")
payload = json.dumps({
        "versions": DictList
})

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': bearer_token
}
```

Below is an example of my results, the first record doesn’t even have a bounding box value, so I don’t understand why it’s showing up. I’ve bolded all the fields that I requested, though there are plenty showing up that were not requested. Am I just making the request incorrectly?

[b'
{"svf2Id":1,
"otgId":1,
"lineageId":"26566104",
"**externalId**":"a",
"**lmvId**":1,
"**databaseId**":"845d10b",
"props":{
"p0f5175c3":"File",
"p137c14f2":"Navisworks 2023",
"p1490bcea":true,
"p153cb174":"LUT_FP_L3.nwc",
"p1bbf1666":false,
"p3474f09f":"File",
"p66e3d0f5":5,
"p74a9a490":"nwd",
"p8c28bc24":"AutoCAD Color Index 7",
"p98b87e0c":"LcNwcLoaderPlugin:lclddwg",
"pb14a0963":"Inches",
"pbc73c467":false,
"pf45e252d":"LUT_FP_L3.nwc"},
"propsHash":"aa8e905",
"propsIgnored":{"pdb5a18d4":"53843524-4bdf-5546-aa0b-f928c739b168"},
"views":["41476be7"]}\n

{"svf2Id":1882,
"otgId":1882,
"lineageId":"26566104",
"**externalId**":"0/0",
"**lmvId**":3,
"**databaseId**":"845d10b",
"props":{
"p0f5175c3":"Geometry",
"p153cb174":"HYDRAPIPE",
"p1bbf1666":false,
"p3474f09f":"HYDRAPIPE",
"p378e758e":"Fire Protection -Drops",
"p56e78f82":"LUT_FP_L3.dwg",
"p66e3d0f5":2,
"p7ce79b6d":"2F5",
"p8c28bc24":"AutoCAD Color Index 1",
"pbc73c467":false,"pf45e252d":"Fire Protection -Drops"},
"propsHash":"134a6978",
"propsIgnored":{"p93e93af5":2,"pdb5a18d4":"cf3266ce-b1ec-5f90-967e-1b21dc67f1c1"},
"geomHash":"0zijcf/jg1ZPF7LGlTJjxw",
"**bboxMin**":{
"x":-7.880555111375819,
"y":28.467788208502906,
"z":49.32679999762991},
"**bboxMax**":{
"x":-7.8471540493641,
"y":28.501187720221655,
"z":50.29199999157408},
"views":["41476be7"]}\n

Answer (score 0):

In columns, you specified a few properties, but in the properties list, it looks many others are returned. I would think you downloaded index properties which means all properties, instead of query properties which will follow the column.

i.e.after calling back-status (with query and column), call

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/index/v2/projects/:projectId/indexes/:indexId/queries/queryId

If this does not resolve your question, we can dig into further.